# Nginx. При любом тексте после слеша в адресе не переадресует на главную. Как исправить?

Tags: nginx, php-nginx

Поднял лендинг на nginx. 
Всё ок. Но если допустим написать в адресной site.com/fwefs0-fs-9dfusd9 и перейти, то в адресе и остается эта билибирда. Но хотелось бы чтобы в случае подобного был редирект на главную страницу..

Конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com;

      location / {
        root   /var/www/site.com;
        index  index.php;
      try_files $uri =503;
    }
     location ~ \.php$ {
        set $root_path /var/www/site.com;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $root_path$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $root_path;
    }
  error_page 503 /index.php;

}
```

Что я неправильно указал в конфиге?

Спасибо заранее

Comment: В конфиге, везде, вместо  503 укажите 404.

Comment: @Jigius Спасибо. А удалять ненужный хвост  в конце? после /

Comment: через редирект. Смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В случае несуществующего uri - редирект на главную:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site.com;

  location / {
    root   /var/www/site.com;
    index  index.php;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect2mainpage;
  }

  location @redirect2mainpage {
    return 302 /;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    set $root_path /var/www/site.com;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $root_path$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $root_path;
  }
  #error_page 404 /error404.php;
}
```